# Implementing PHP Pagination for a SQLite query set

Tags: php, pagination

I'm looking for a good function for implementing pagination in a PHP site. The solution needs to work for vanilla PHP (no template language, no frameworks, etc). I'd like to be able to put something like the following in my code:

```
<? $widgets = ... (some query)?>
Page content here.
<?= paginate($widgets) ?>
```

This would output something like the following:

```
Page content here.
1 <a href='?page=2'>2</a> <a href='?page=3'>3</a> . . .
```

Then, there is the issue of filtering my query. I could query twice, once to get a count of total objects and once with a limit clause to get the specific "widgets" that I need.

Are there any simple PHP functions that can elegantly encapsulate this functionality, or is it something best done by hand? I think I've become spoiled by [django-pagination](http://eflorenzano.com/blog/post/first-two-django-screencasts/#using-django-pagination), but this project requires a PHP solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PEAR has a pagination class: http://www.codediesel.com/php/simple-pagination-in-php/